# RS232 Serial Console: Do we receive serial packets at serial pin out from CPU even we don't have the console cable connected?

Tags: serial, rs232

What if I don't have the serial cable connected to the serial port, still I receive serial packets from CPU? (lets say console output is enabled in Software)
Will those packets got terminated (discarded) at the serial port connector end at board?

Comment: It's unlikely that these are "packets" except in the sense that log messages may typically be distinct newline-terminated lines of text...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What if I don't have the serial cable connected to the serial port, still I receive serial packets from CPU?

The CPU will still send data. It doesn't know there isn't a cable.

> Will those packets got terminated (discarded) at the serial port connector end at board?

The CPU makes the voltage go up and down on the pin, and then... nothing happens, because there is no cable. The CPU doesn't know that nothing is happening when it makes the voltage go up and down.

Comment: Unless of course there is hardware flow control involved.